# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute on click method of the activity

Tags: android

I am very new to android development. I started creating a navigation drawer with fragments i want call navigation fragments form different different activity I attached my codes for ur review. please suggest me the solution.

```js
And this is my fragment which we r calling

package com.example.lunetta;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

 ImageView ivIcon;
 TextView tvItemName;

 public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
 public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

 public FragmentTwo()
 {
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
  View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_two,container, false);
  
  return view;
 }

}



here is my error
03-26 12:35:23.231: W/dalvikvm(5062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  ... 11 more
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.lunetta/com.example.lunetta.FragmentTwo}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  at com.example.lunetta.Second.aboutUsClick(Second.java:41)
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):  ... 14 more
```

```css
here is my navigation drawer class

package com.example.lunetta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Welcome extends Activity {
 private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
 private ListView mDrawerList;
 private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

 private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
 private CharSequence mTitle;
 CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

 List<DrawerItem> dataList;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

  // Initializing
  dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
  mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
  mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
    GravityCompat.START);

  // Add Drawer Item to dataList
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Home", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem(" About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Services", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Product", R.drawable.ic_action_labels));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Marketing", R.drawable.ic_action_search));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Portfolio", R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("career", R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Request", R.drawable.ic_action_video));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Contact", R.drawable.ic_action_group));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export",
    R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Likes", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
  dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));

  adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
    dataList);

  mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

  mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
    R.string.drawer_close) {
   public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
           // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
   }

   public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
           // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
   }
  };

  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   SelectItem(0);
  }

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
  return true;
 }

 public void SelectItem(int possition) {

  Fragment fragment = null;
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  switch (possition) {
  case 0:
   fragment = new FragmentOne();
   args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
     .getImgResID());
   break;
  case 1:
   fragment = new FragmentTwo();

   break;
  case 2:
   fragment = new FragmentThree();
   args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
     .get(possition).getImgResID());
   break;
  case 3:
   fragment = new FragmentOne();
   args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
     .getImgResID());
   break;
  case 4:
   fragment = new FragmentTwo();
   args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
     .getImgResID());
   break;
  case 5:
   fragment = new FragmentThree();
   args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
     .get(possition).getImgResID());
   break;
  case 6:
   fragment = new FragmentOne();
   args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
     .getImgResID());
   break;
  case 7:
   fragment = new FragmentTwo();
   args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
     .getImgResID());
   break;
  case 8:
   fragment = new FragmentThree();
   args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
     .get(possition).getImgResID());
   break;
  case 9:
   fragment = new FragmentOne();
   args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
     .getImgResID());
   break;
  case 10:
   fragment = new FragmentTwo();
   args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
     .getImgResID());
   break;
  case 11:
   fragment = new FragmentThree();
   args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
     .get(possition).getImgResID());
   break;
  case 12:
   fragment = new FragmentOne();
   args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
     .getItemName());
   args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
     .getImgResID());
   break;
  default:
   break;
  }

  fragment.setArguments(args);
  FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
  frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
    .commit();

  mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
  setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

 }

 @Override
 public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
  mTitle = title;
  getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
  mDrawerToggle.syncState();
 }

 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
  mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
  // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
   return true;
  } else if (id == R.id.action_Home) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Second.class);
   startActivity(intent);
  } else if (id == R.id.action_Contact) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Contact.class);
   startActivity(intent);
  }

  return false;
 }

 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
   ListView.OnItemClickListener {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
   SelectItem(position);

  }

 }

}
```

```html
Main class here my all activity class

package com.example.lunetta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Second extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

 }

 public void onClickNext(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 400);
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top);
 }

 public void btnHome(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Welcome.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

 public void aboutUsClick(View view) {

  Fragment fragment = new FragmentTwo();
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, FragmentTwo.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
  frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
    .commit();

 }

 public void serviceClick(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Services.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

 public void productClicked(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Product.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

 public void marketingClicked(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Marketing.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

 public void portfilioClicked(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Portfolio.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

 public void careerlicked(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Career.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

 public void requestClicked(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Request.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

 public void contactClicked(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Contact.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

}
```

```css
Here is my manifest file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lunetta"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/lunettaa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Welcome"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            
            android:name=".Contact"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutUs"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Services"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_services" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Product"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_product" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Marketing"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_marketing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Portfolio"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_portfolio" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Career"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_career" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Request"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_request" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.lunetta/com.example.lunetta.FragmentTwo}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Check whether you have declared all activities in Manifiest file

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all activitys in the AndroidManifest.xml. Inside tag application. Something like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.gui.SecondActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

If the activity is the first you show, you should declare like this:

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.example.gui.FisrtActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace:

```
03-26 12:35:23.261: E/AndroidRuntime(5062):     at com.example.lunetta.Second.aboutUsClick(Second.java:41)
```

This line  points to:

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentTwo();
Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, FragmentTwo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You cannot use `startActivity` to start `FragmentTwo` because it is a `Fragment` subclass, not an `Activity` subclass.